# Javascript regex - no white space at beginning + allow space in the middle

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to have a regex which matches the string with NO whitespace(s) at the beginning. But the string containing whitespace(s) in the middle CAN match. So far i have tried below

```
[^-\s][a-zA-Z0-9-_\\s]+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/yINyI0zcVB8ZnsgC)

Above is not allowing whitespace(s) at the beginning, but also not allowing in the middle/end of the string. Please help me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your 2nd character class, `\\s` will match `\` and `s`, and not `\s`. Thus it doesn't matches a whitespace. You should use just `\s` there. Also, move the hyphen towards the end, else it will create unintentional range in character class:

```
^[^-\s][a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]+$
```

Answer (score 11):

If you plan to match a string of any length (even an empty string) that matches your pattern *and* does not start with a whitespace, use `(?!\s)` right after `^`:

```
/^(?!\s)[a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]*$/
  ^^^^^^
```

Or, bearing in mind that `[A-Za-z0-9_]` in JS regex is equal to `\w`:

```
/^(?!\s)[\w\s-]*$/
```

The `(?!\s)` is a **negative lookahead** that matches a location in string that is not immediately followed with a whitespace (matched with the `\s` pattern).

If you want to add more "forbidden" chars at the string start (it looks like you also disallow `-`) keep using the `[\s-]` character class in the lookahead:

```
/^(?![\s-])[\w\s-]*$/
```

To match at least 1 character, replace `*` with `+`:

```
/^(?![\s-])[\w\s-]+$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3cZsk9/1). JS demo:

```js
console.log(/^(?![\s-])[\w\s-]+$/.test("abc   def 123 ___ -loc-   "));
console.log(/^(?![\s-])[\w\s-]+$/.test("  abc   def 123 ___ -loc-   "));
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use this regex:

```
^[^-\s][\w\s-]+$
```

- Use start anchor `^`
- No need to double escape `\s`
- Also important is to use hyphen as the first OR last character in the character class.
- `\w` is same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 7):

use \S at the beginning

```
^\S+[a-zA-Z0-9-_\\s]+$
```

Answer (score 4):

This RegEx will allow neither white-space at the beginning nor at the end of. Your string/word and allows all the special characters.

```
^[^\s].+[^\s]$
```

This Regex also works Fine

```
^[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$
```

Answer (score 1):

try this should work

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]+.*$
```

Answer (score 1):

/^[^.\s]/

- try this instead it will not allow a user to enter character at first place
- ^ matches position just before the first character of the string
- . matches a single character. Does not matter what character it is, except newline
- \s is space

Answer (score 1):

If your field for user name only accept letters and middle of space but not for begining and end

**User name:** `/^[^\s][a-zA-Z\s]+[^\s]$/`

If your field for user ID only accept letters,numbers and underscore and no spaces allow

**user ID:** `/^[\w]+$/`

If your field for password only accept letters,number and special character no spaces allow

**Password:** `/^[\w@#&]+$/`

Note: `\w` content `a-zA-Z`, `number`, underscore (`_`) if you add more character, add you special character after `\w`.

You can compare with user ID and password field in password field im only add some special character (`@#&`).

India public thoko like

Answer (score 0):

I suggest below regex for this,

`^[^\s].*[^\s]$`

You can try regex in [here](https://regex101.com/)