# Regex for Cloudinary Public ID

Tags: javascript, regex, cloudinary

I need the (javascript) regex needed to validate a Cloudinary Public ID. The rules are:

The Public ID format supports **all printable characters except for the following reserved characters: ? & # \ % < >**. In addition, **spaces and forward slashes (/) cannot be used as the first or last character** of the Public ID.

Tried this but it's not working: `^[^\s\\]+[^?&#\%<>]+$`

I was referencing these SO questions: [Javascript regex - no white space at beginning + allow space in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973669/javascript-regex-no-white-space-at-beginning-allow-space-in-the-middle) and [Regex - Does not contain certain Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105956/regex-does-not-contain-certain-characters)

Comment: Can you provide us a few examples of the ID?

Comment: I was only given one example: ufu6dphq8hhos0kiyhtx

Comment: You forgot to take in account your second condition regarding the end of the ID. You need to add to the end of the regex (before the `$`): `[^\s\\]+`. In addition, you need to escape the "\" inside the unaccepted characters.

Comment: @GalAbra You're right, but unfortunately I couldn't even get past the first part of putting together the "no ^?&#\%<> characters" with "no spaces at the beginning".

Comment: @steve-o I've edited my comment - you need to escape the "\" with "\\"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(?![ \/])(?!.*[ \/]$)(?!.*[?&#\%<>])[ -~]+$
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MRA3ZD/3)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(?![ \/])` - negative lookahead to validate that the neither a space nor a `/` is at the start of the string
- `(?!.*[ \/]$)` - negative lookahead to validate that the neither a space nor a `/` is at the end of the string
- `(?!.*[?&#\%<>])` - negative lookahead to make sure that none of these characters are found in the string `[?&#\%<>]`
- `[ -~]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of printable ascii characters(space to `~`)
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

Comment: This is pretty good but won't accept unicode characters (é) will it?

Comment: @NickChapman You are right. But I am not sure if the input string has unicode characters. Hence, I asked for sample input strings from OP