# No white space at beginning + allow space in the middle

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex for detecting @xxx

```
/(?:@)(.*[a-zA-Z0-9]*)/
```

it matches even when the @xxx is not separated from another string from the left (when it's typed in the middle of an input line).

**xxx@xxx** will match too so i added \s to require a space in the begining .Now it's

```
/\s(?:@)(.*[a-zA-Z0-9]*)/
```

But the problem is there isn't a match when the @xxx is typed in the begining of a  line (the white space is still required) and i need it match in that case.

I tried to get inspired by [https://stackoverflow.com/a/19973707/170592](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19973707/1705922) so i added **^[^-\s]** in the begining of the regex to make it

```
/^[^-\s](?:@)(.*[a-zA-Z0-9]*)/
```

But it didn't work neither.

Comment: If you want to match start of a line or whitespace, use `/(?:^|\s)@(.*)/gm`. Note `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` is meaningless after `.*`. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55777608/3832970).

Comment: Yes, or `(?<!\S)@(.*)` or `(?<!\S)@[a-zA-Z0-9]+` matching only the characters from the character class.

Comment: thanks for all it did work

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are looking for it is `/\S+/` which means that check for any non-whitespace and I don't think you need the ^ at the beginning.

`[-\S+](?:@)(.*[a-zA-Z0-9]*)`